# Unable to finish Gitlab-CI job

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have CI setup, that deploy changes to the server. Everything works perfect, changes are pulled to server, but when all tasks are ended, runner still waiting:

[image]

What is wrong? It should be finished with success.

Here is the **.gitlab-ci.yml**:

```
stages:
  - deploy
before_script:
  # Setup SSH deploy keys
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 --decode)

deploy_staging:
  type: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: example.com
  script:
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@example.com "cd public_html/gitlab-test && git checkout master && git pull origin master && exit"
  only:
    - master
```

Update:

Output:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.6.1 (8d829975)
  on Shared heeGPy6w
Using Shell executor...
Running on demeter...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at 4eaccda Update .gitlab-ci.yml
From https://git.example.com/user/ssh-test
   4eaccda..ce1729c  master     -> origin/master
Checking out ce1729c4 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 14151
$ ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 --decode)
Identity added: /dev/fd/63 (/dev/fd/63)
$ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@example.com "cd public_html/gitlab-test && git checkout master && git pull origin master"
Already on 'master'
From https://git.example.com/user/ssh-test
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   4eaccda..ce1729c  master     -> origin/master
Updating 4eaccda..ce1729c
Fast-forward
 .gitlab-ci.yml | 3 ++-
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
$ exit 0
```

and after this, still waiting...

Comment: What will happen if you return some "exit code"? Try to replace end of the command `..&& exit` with `..&& exit 0`
Or try to add `exit 0` on new line (after `ssh -o ...`)

Comment: Unfortunately, the same - still waiting.

Comment: Do you use shared runners or self hosted?

Comment: Self-hosted. I've just added complete output to my answer.

Comment: So the problem is that it doesn't exit the SSH session? Maybe this one can help you: https://superuser.com/questions/467398/how-do-i-exit-a-ssh-connection. Furthermore, you could try `ssh -t [...]`.

Comment: If I log to ssh by console, there is no problem with logout with `exit` command. Problem is in the CI setup (I suppose)

Comment: I located problem in line `- eval $(ssh-agent -s)`. When i comment this, runner can finish job, but connection with `ssh` doesn't work.

Comment: FYI: Using before_script at the top level is deprecated. [Ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#globally-defined-image-services-cache-before_script-after_script]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I resolved my problem.

Reason was in line `- eval $(ssh-agent -s)` - when I commented it, the job could be finished (but of course, connection didn't work). So, I attempted add killing command at the end of script:

```
- eval $(ssh-agent -k)
```

It was a solution. Now everything works excellent.

Finally code:

```
stages:
  - deploy
before_script:
  # Setup SSH deploy keys
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 --decode)

deploy_staging:
  type: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: example.com
  script:
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@example.com "cd public_html/gitlab-test && git checkout master && git pull origin master && exit 0"
    - eval $(ssh-agent -k)
  only:
    - master
```